AI OCR software for a person with vision impairment
I have a colleague who has vision impairment.
If he has to read text, that is OK, he has text-to-speech software.
But if he receives any graph, the OCR fails. eg.:

The Question: is there any AI-based OCR software that can check an image on the screen and say out loud what is on that given graph? eg.:
this graph is about "temperature on 1st of September" and has an increasing temperature from 2C to 16C from 09am to 4pm with some stagnation at 10C from 12pm to 3pm
or there could be pictures that has more graphs, not just one..

I think you are asking too much of AI, which isnt  really AI at the moment.  Its just pattern matching

should i ask on https://ai.stackexchange.com/ ? or am i asking in the right forum with softwarerecs ? Thanks!

TTS and OCR are not the same thing.  OCR interprets text contained in images. TTS reads text aloud. What tool  (app name and platform/OS) are they currently using that is working for  "Text" ?  This will make it clearer what is required of the tool.  Is there any budgetary restriction?

he is using it on windows

More of a FYI: on the mobile side iOS seems to have https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accessibility/audio-graphs and I started a discussion for the Android side https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions/78552873/how-could-android-provide-a-function-similar-to-ios-audio-graph with some thoughts about implementation.

@peterK88 you are asking in the correct place, he meant OCR isn't AI, but that's not quite true as bunch of OCR tools are using AI. But the question is not good as said above as you should be looking for a combo of OCR and TTS, as OCR alone won't do anything for a visually impaired person. It's also not really OCR to analyze random graphs, that's a step further. OCR reads text, as the name suggests.
